# calculating input value of scope variable in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i have made a textfield and i want to show the calculated value of the numbers (inputted in the textfiled) inside a div. my html:

```
<input ng-model="inp" type="text"/><br/>
<div>{{equateInp}}</div>
```

angularjs:

```
$scope.inp = "";
    $scope.equateInp = parseInt($scope.inp);
```

but it is not working. Pls help

Comment: did you configure a controller the right way?

Comment: some of your more code might help us help you

Comment: Please include the complete code of your controller

Comment: You Can use default Filter for numbers.
 `Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  No fractions: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span><br>
  Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:4}}</span>`

Comment: If you only want to display whatever value that is typed in the textbox, then you just use `<div>{{inp}}</div>`. This is enough. You don't need to use parseInt() and all that stuff

Answer (score 1):

Pls try This

```
<input ng-model="inp" type="number"/><br/>
{{inp}}
```

Comment: does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type = "number" ng-model = "inpNumber">
 <div>{{inpNumber}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Example,

```
<input ng-model="inp" type="text"/><br/>
<div>{{calculate(inp)}}</div>

$scope.equateInp = function(inp) {
    // do your calculation here 
    //eg:
    c = parseInt(inp) + 10
    return c
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc4yjpcn/1/),

Answer (score 0):

The integer is a primitive javascript type and the 2-way binding does not work on primitive types. So, you need to either assign your 2-way bound model with an object property or use `ng-change`. SInce in yourcase you need to perform some manipulation on your model (`parseInt`), you can use the second option of using ng-change as below:

**JS:**

```
$scope.user = {
  inp: 0
};

$scope.onChange = function () {
  $scope.equateInp = parseInt($scope.user.inp);    
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="user.inp" 
       ng-change='onChange()'
       type="text"/>
<br/>
<div>{{equateInp}}</div>
```

A working JSBin for this is available here: https://jsbin.com/nuxaqak/edit?html,js,console,output

EDIT: Updated JSBin for handling evaluation of expressions
https://jsbin.com/nuxaqak/edit?html,js,output

Comment: soryy sir, but i dont get 10 value when i type 5+5 in the input

Comment: But your question does not mentions that you will enter an expression. It just says `calculated value of the numbers`. Please edit your question to mention the exact expectation

Answer (score 0):

It seems like to me that you are trying to watch for changes in the inp var calculating the value and outputing the result.
there are multiple ways to accomplish this.

**using $watch:**

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="inp" type="text"/><br/>
<div>{{ equateInp }}</div>
```

**angularjs:**

```
$scope.inp = "";

$scope.$watch('inc', function() {
    $scope.equateInp = parseInt($scope.inp);
})
```

this basically watches when the inc variable is changed.

**using a calculation method:**

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="inp" type="text"/><br/>
<div>{{ calculate(inp) }}</div>
```

**angularjs:**

```
$scope.inp = "";

$scope.calculate = function(value) {
    return ($scope.inp * 5);
}
```

this runs the calculate method every time the variable is changed